# angularjs dynamic checkbox. How to extend form and submit?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to dynamically create a form for an array of users and per user show their available options.

so far so good. the problem is that depending on the selection of one option, an extra textinput needs to be shown and attached to the option itself.

how should I "ng-model" that extra option? when i try to use user.SelectedOption[option.Id].ExtraInfo the inputfield becomes disabled.

anyone got an idea (or a better solution)?

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <h1>{{user.UserName}}</h1>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="options in user.Options>
            <th>{{option.Name}}</th>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.SelectedOption[option.Id]" /><td>
            <td>
                <p ng-show="user.SelectedOption[option.Id] === true">
                    <label>Remarks</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="????" >
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td>
    </table>
</div>



<button type="primary" ng-click="save()">save<button>
```

The user-object would look something like this (simplified)

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "UserName": "testname",
            "Options": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "Name": "strawberry"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "Name": "chocolate"
                }
            ]
        },
         {
            "Id": 2,
            "UserName": "testname2",
            "Options": [

                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "Name": "chocolate"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And as for response I want something like this

```
{
"selectedOptions" : [
                        {
                            "UserId" : 1,
                            "Options" : [
                                            {
                                                "id": 1,
                                                "Selected": false,
                                                "Remarks" : null
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": 2,
                                                "Selected": true,
                                                "Remarks" : "Lorem Ipsum"
                                            }
                                        ]
                        },
                                                {
                            "UserId" : 2,
                            "Options" : [

                                            {
                                                "id": 2,
                                                "Selected": true,
                                                "Remarks" : "Lorem Ipsum"
                                            }
                                        ]
                        }
                    ]

}
```

---Actually I was able to create a somewhat working form with this:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "UserName": "testname",
            "Options": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "Name": "strawberry",
                    "isSelected" : false,
                    "Remarks" : ""
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "Name": "chocolate",
                    "isSelected" : false,
                    "Remarks" : ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "UserName": "testname2",
            "Options": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "Name": "chocolate",
                    "isSelected" : false,
                    "Remarks" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <h1>{{user.UserName}}</h1>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="options in user.Options>
            <th>{{option.Name}}</th>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="options.isSelected" /><td>
            <td>
                <p ng-show="options.isSelected === true">
                    <label>Remarks</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="options.Remarks" >
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td>
    </table>
</div>



<button type="primary" ng-click="save()">save<button>
```

But somehow I don't think that's the "correct" way to handle the response object.

Comment: It would help if you showed what `user` object looks like and how you want to  specify the selected options

Comment: I've extended the intitial posts with the object-codes